# Organizing measures dimension as a hierarchy

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

I need/want to retrieve measures dimension from a Mondrian schema as a hierarchy using a single MDX query. For instance I have 2 dimensions (**Time** and **Company**) and 3 measures (**Cost**, **Income**, **Profit**). 
Profit is a calculated measure **Profit = Income - Cost**.
When a perform a query like:

```
SELECT 
  [Time].Children ON COLUMNS, 
  CrossJoin([Measures].Members, [Company].Children) ON ROWS 
FROM [KPIs]
```

I receive an answer like: 
                                       Time
Measures    Company    2010    2011    2012
Income        C1               100     123      1
                    C2               122     34        10
Cost             C1               99       40        50
                    C2               42       130      5
Profit            C1               1         83      -49
                    C2               80       -96       5
The result that I want to obtain looks like: 
                                       Time
Measures    Company    2010    2011    2012
- Profit         C1               1         83      -49
                    C2               80       -96       5
    + Income C1               100     123      1
                    C2               122     34        10
    + Cost     C1               99       40        50
                    C2               42       130      5

where Cost and Income are children of Profit. I think there might be necessary to change also Mondrian schema in order to specify the child parent relationships between measures.

Thank you in advance for answers!

Comment: In SSAS, I would create a parent child dimension of type account that contains Income, Cost, and Profit as their parent. And have a single measure named e. g. "Amount". I am not sure if that is possible in Mondrian.

Comment: Thank you Frank for the answer! It is also possible to create a self-reference dimension in Mondrian. Suggested solution will work however it will require to execute an MDX query as above but at the leaf level of each dimension and then create and populate a temporary fact table with 2 columns Metric and Amount. I think it will be slow to execute (because of leaf level) & will require a good amount of work!